# Remove consecutive duplicate characters from a string in python

Tags: python, string, duplicates

Hey I was trying to write a program which will remove the consecutive duplicate characters from a string.

for example:
string->aabbccde
first iteration: bbccde
second iteration: ccde
third Iteration: de

and de is the answer.

following is the program I wrote.

```
a = "aabbcs"
def remove_dups(st,ind):
    print st, ind
    st = st.replace(st[ind], "")
    print st, "in dups"
    find_dups(st)

def find_dups(text):
    s=text
    print s, "in find"
    ln = len(s)
    print ln
    fg = 0
    ind = 0
    if ln==1:
        print s, 'len'
        return s
    for i in range(0,ln-1):
        if(s[i]==s[i+1]):
            ind = i
            remove_dups(s,ind)
    print s, 'check'        
    return s

ans = find_dups(a)
print 'answer', ans
```

and following is the output I am getting

aabbcs in find
6
aabbcs 0
bbcs in dups
bbcs in find
4
bbcs 0
cs in dups
cs in find
2
cs check
bbcs check
aabbcs 2
aacs in dups
aacs in find
4
aacs 0
cs in dups
cs in find
2
cs check
aacs check
aabbcs check
answer aabbcs

here above we have got cs but still answer is coming original string, I can understand it is because of recursion, but unable to understand how to resolve the issue. A little help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `remove_dups(s,ind)` is the problem. It's not doing anything with the returned value. If you read through your code, in the top level function call you're assigning `s=text` at the top, then returning `s` at the bottom, without ever modifying the value of `s`. The clue is that you're printing the original text last, after you've printed the correct answer.
Try `s = remove_dups(s, ind)`

Comment: thanks I added `s = remove_dups(s,ind)` and this `s = find_dups(s)` rest it worked

Answer (score 3):

python have some easier way to do this, one of them:

```
>>> dup_string = 'aabcbccde'
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> ''.join([x for x,y in groupby(dup_string) if sum(1 for i in y)<2])
'bcbde'
>>> dup_string = 'aabbccde'
>>> ''.join([x for x,y in groupby(dup_string) if sum(1 for i in y)<2])
'de'
>>>
```

Comment: I suspect that a string ending in `ded` will require an output of `ded` since there're not immediately consecutive letters. This will output `de` still... and `abcbca` will return an empty string and there's nothing consecutive at all...

Comment: this time should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to call the `find_dups` method recursively, you might as well get rid of the for loop. Just remove the consecutive duplicates as soon as you find them, and then recursively call `find_dups` again on the newly returned string.

```
a = "aabbcs"
def remove_dups(st,ind):
     return st.replace(st[ind:ind+1], "")


def find_dups(text, i):
    if len(text)-1 == i:
        return text
    if(text[i]==text[i+1]):
        text = remove_dups(text,i)
        text = find_dups(text, i)
    else:
        text = find_dups(text, i+1)
    return text

ans = find_dups(a, 0)
print "answer", ans
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do it using `re.sub`

```
import re
str = "aaaabbcccdddx"
print(re.sub(r"(.)\1+", '', str))
```

**OP**

```
x
```

Comment: Almost - you want `''` though as the replacement string so the output matches the `de` the OP is expecting...

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning the values of the string, since these are passed by copies. Also once you are done with `remove_dups` you should break out since you are no longer interested in the same you just modified.

```
a = "aabbcs"
def remove_dups(st,ind):
    print st, ind
    st = st.replace(st[ind], "")
    print st, "in dups"
    return find_dups(st)

def find_dups(text):
    s=text
    print s, "in find"
    ln = len(s)
    print ln
    fg = 0
    ind = 0
    if ln==1:
        print s, 'len'
        return s
    for i in range(0,ln-1):
        if(s[i]==s[i+1]):
            ind = i
            s = remove_dups(s,ind)
            break
    print s, 'check'        
    return s
ans = find_dups(a)
print 'answer', ans
```

Answer (score 0):

bellow is your function to do the job

```
def remove_duplicates(str):
  integer=0
  while integer<len(str)-1:
      if str[integer]==str[integer+1]:
          str=str.replace(str[integer]," ",2)
      integer=integer+1    
  str=str.replace(" ","")
  print(str)
```

you can include the print statements that i left out!

Answer (score 0):

For general list:

```
mylist = [['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['b'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['a'], ['a']]
idx = 0
while True:
    if idx == len(mylist) - 1:
         break
    if mylist[idx] == mylist[idx + 1]:
         del mylist[idx + 1]
         idx = idx
    else:
         idx = idx + 1
```