# Removing specific duplicated characters from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, text, set

How i can delete specific duplicated characters from a string only if they goes one after one in Python? For example:

A have string

```
string = "Hello _my name is __Alex"
```

I need to delete duplicate _ only if they goes one after one __ and get string like this:

```
string = "Hello _my name is _Alex"
```

If i use set i got this:

```
string = "_yoiHAemnasxl"
```

Comment: `itertools.groupby` probably the way to go

Comment: What do you mean by "specific characters"?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre not sure if this is a dupe of that question- in this question, OP wants to keep one of the duplicated chars where in the dupe they remove all of them. Something like RomanPerekhrest's answer here is different and useful, IMO.

Comment: Why does "_" get de-duplicated but not the two Ls in "Hello"? What criteria are we using to decide what should be deleted?

Comment: I undup-ed this since [Remove consecutive duplicate characters from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40704821/364696) wants to remove *all* characters if they're duplicated, this one just wants to reduce them to a single copy; the differences in how you solve that are enough to make many answers to the not-a-duplicate a poor fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Big edit: oops, I missed that you only want to de-deuplicate certain characters and not others. Retrofitting solutions...)

I assume you have a string that represents all the characters you want to de-duplicate. Let's call it `to_remove`, and say that it's equal to "_.-". So only underscores, periods, and hyphens will be de-duplicated.

You could use a regex to match multiple successive repeats of a character, and replace them with a single character.

```
>>> import re
>>> to_remove = "_.-"
>>> s = "Hello... _my name -- is __Alex"
>>> pattern = "(?P<char>[" + re.escape(to_remove) + "])(?P=char)+"
>>> re.sub(pattern, r"\1", s)
'Hello. _my name - is _Alex'
```

Quick breakdown:

- `?P<char>` assigns the symbolic name `char` to the first group.
- we put `to_remove` inside the character matching set, `[]`. It's necessary to call re.escape because hyphens and other characters may have special meaning inside the set otherwise.
- `(?P=char)` refers back to the character matched by the named group "char".
- The `+` matches one or more repetitions of that character.

So in aggregate, this means "match any character from `to_remove` that appears more than once in a row". The second argument to `sub`, `r"\1"`, then replaces that match with the first group, which is only one character long.

---

Alternative approach: write a generator expression that takes only characters that don't match the character preceding them.

```
>>> "".join(s[i] for i in range(len(s)) if i == 0 or not (s[i-1] == s[i] and s[i] in to_remove))
'Hello. _my name - is _Alex'
```

---

Alternative approach #2: use `groupby` to identify consecutive identical character groups, then join the values together, using `to_remove` membership testing to decide how many values should be added..

```
>>> import itertools
>>> "".join(k if k in to_remove else "".join(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(s, lambda c: c))
'Hello. _my name - is _Alex'
```

---

Alternative approach #3: call `re.sub` once for each member of to_remove. A bit expensive if `to_remove` contains a lot of characters.

```
>>> for c in to_remove:
...     s = re.sub(rf"({re.escape(c)})\1+", r"\1", s)
...
>>> s
'Hello. _my name - is _Alex'
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple `re.sub()` approach:

```
import re

s = "Hello _my name is __Alex aa"
result = re.sub(r'(\S)\1+', '\\1', s)

print(result)
```

- `\S` - any non-whitespace character
- `\1+` - backreference to the 1st parenthesized captured group (one or more occurrences)

The output:

```
Helo _my name is _Alex a
```

Comment: Oh, neat. This is more concise than my answer, since I didn't know you could refer to a previous group without explicitly naming it.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it turns out I may have been wrong and your first answer may have actually been correct. I regret the error, but this is a great solution!

Comment: how to keep "Hello" word?